# Bluetooth (Atheros AR3012) not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: bluetooth, atheros

I have a Zenbook UX21 and I'm not able to get bluetooth up and running.
I've just installed blueman and bluez, but I'm still not able to connect devices because they are not found.

uname -a

```
Linux daniel-UX21E 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsusb | grep -i "bluetooth"

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 13d3:3375 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
```

hcitool dev

```
Devices:
```

(empty list)

rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Edit: Jeremy helped me to fix my problem temporary (sudo hciconfig hci0 up).

Unfortunately, Bluetooth is not working after I restarted my notebook.
hciconfig -a does not list a device, all other commands return the same as before (see comments below). I had to start the bluez daemon manually.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status -l
```

says

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Mit 2015-06-10 09:10:33 CEST; 30min ago
Main PID: 3096 (bluetoothd)
  CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       └─3096 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n
```

Comment: Do you see a list of files using this command `ls /lib/firmware/ar3k`  Also do `modprobe -c | grep 3375 | grep ath3k` does terminal return ath3k?

Comment: Yes I do. Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Any errors reported in `dmesg | grep -i firmware; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

Comment: everything, except the first line seems quite good:
[    0.143444] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

Comment: And that firmware bug is normal.  Was there anything else?

Comment: Not really. Just messages like "HCI device initialized" and "HCI socket initialized" or "usb 3-1.1: product: bluetooth usb host controller"

Comment: what does `hciconfig -a` show, if anything

Comment: hci0: Type BR/EDR, Bus: USB and additional information but nothing like an error

Comment: Did it say UP or DOWN under BD Address?

Comment: DOWN. thx for your help btw.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, getting bluetooth working should just involve

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

Since it seems to forget this setting after a reboot

```
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/90-bluetooth.rules
```

and paste the following into the file

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", TEST=="/usr/sbin/hciconfig", RUN+="/usr/sbin/hciconfig hci0 up"
```

Save, exit program and reboot to test

Comment: It works like a charm now. Thank you so much for your help, Jeremy!

Comment: But I'm not sure if it's really solved since it's not working properly. After rebooting my notebook it is not working anymore...

Comment: Are you using Kubuntu?

Comment: Nope. It's Ubuntu.

Comment: @Daniel Is it blocked by rfkill?

Comment: No it's neither hard nor soft blocked.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a suggestion. There is updated firmware.

Comment: Tried your updated answer without success. Executed in terminal hciconfig hci0 up says "Can't get device info: No such device"

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/90-bluetooth.rules` reboot and see if it finds device.  If it doesn't find a device check `dmesg | grep firmware` for errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to install new firmware for this device.

You can download it from [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012~vivid_all.deb)

It can also be installed by adding ppa

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Comment: Blueman still says that no adapters were found.

Comment: @Daniel You need to turn off the computer (not reboot) and turn it on again after you added the firmware.